# What is the best way to remotely manage a Sqlite DB?

Tags: sqlite, remote-administration

We have an Sqlite DB on our Linux/PHP production webserver. What is the best way to manage it remotely? I've found some server wrappers are available and some applications claim to offer remote access methods. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH in and use the SQLite command-line client.

But...why are you using SQLite on a *production* webserver!? Even the SQLite website advises against this!

Comment: Why can't it be used for production web server? See http://www.sqlite.org/features.html where they actually recommend it for this purpose.

Comment: I'm manipulating an existing client's Shopsite DB which uses SQLite behind the scenes. There's nothing inherently wrong with using SQLite in production for sites with low/moderate traffic. - http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Answer (score 1):

[Gindi's SQLITE client/server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLite_Server.aspx) at Codeproject looks like an interesting and serious attempt at a wrapper.